# Looping until a specific string is found

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have a simple question. I want to write a program in C that scans the lines of a specific file, and if the only phrase on the line is "Atoms", I want it to stop scanning and report which line it was on. This is what I have and is not compiling because apparently I'm comparing an integer to a pointer: (of course "string.h" is included.

```
char dm;
  int test; 
  test = fscanf(inp,"%s", &dm);

  while (test != EOF) {
    if (dm=="Amit") {
      printf("Found \"Atoms\" on line %d", j);
      break;
    }
    j++;
  }
```

the file was already opened with:

`inp = fopen( .. )`

And checked to make sure it opens correctly...

I would like to use a different approach though, and was wondering if it could work. Instead of scanning individual strings, could I scan entire lines as such:

```
// char tt[200];
//
// fgets(tt, 200, inp);
```

and do something like:

`if (tt[] == "Atoms") break;`

Thanks!
Amit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without paying too much attention to your actual code here, the most important mistake your making is that the == operator will NOT compare two strings.

In C, a string is an array of characters, which is simply a pointer.  So doing if("abcde" == some_string) will never be true unless they point to the same string!

You want to use a method like "strcmp(char *a, char *b)" which will return 0 if two strings are equal and something else if they're not.  "strncmp(char *a, char *b, size_t n)" will compare the first "n" characters in a and b, and return 0 if they're equal, which is good for looking at the beginning of strings (to see if a string starts with a certain set of characters)

You also should NOT be passing a character as the pointer for %s in your fscanf!  This will cause it to completely destroy your stack it tries to put many characters into ch, which only has space for a single character!  As James says, you want to do something like char ch[BUFSIZE] where BUFSIZE is 1 larger than you ever expect a single line to be, then do "fscanf(inp, "%s", ch);"

Hope that helps!

Comment: I don't appear to be able to comment on other's answers yet, but I would like to point out that John's advice below is NOT GOOD.

You have to initialize the pointer to a valid block of memory before having fscanf attempt to store data there!  Calling the code he gave below is VERY DANGEROUS as the pointer could be pointing anywhere!

Comment: Thanks @Kit. I ended up using strncmp, which is why I changed the answer to yours. I think it works a lot better for my case and I was not aware of this strncmp function. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm glad I could help! I'm sorry my answer was so wordy, but I tried to pack as many tidbits in there as I could.

Answer (score 1):

please be aware that dm is a ***single*** char, while you need a char *

more: `if (dm=="Amit")` is wrong, change it in

```
if (strcmp(dm, "Amit") == 0)
```

Comment: `if(strcmp(dm,"Amit")==0)` seems better.

Comment: I agree. strcmp is the correct function. Is there a reason it's returning "7" for a true comparison and negative numbers for incorrect comparison? For example, if I compare two identical strings: `int test = strcmp(s1,s2)`, it will return test = 7, and negative numbers otherwise

Comment: @Amit: the man page says: RETURN VALUE
       The strcmp() and strncmp() functions return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if s1 (or the first n bytes thereof) is found, respectively, to be less  than,  to
       match, or be greater than s2. (Where s1 = dm and s2 = "Amit" in our previous example)

Comment: @Ass3mbler: So it should be returning 0 given two strings are identical, no?

Comment: Darn it. I forgot the \n. What a shame. Thanks, this did it.

Comment: One more side question: how come I can't do: `while (fgets(tt, 200, input_file) != EOF ) { // do something }`

Answer (score 1):

In the line using fscanf, you are casting a string to the address of a char.  Using the %s in fscanf should set the string to a pointer, not an address:

```
char *dm;
test = fscanf(inp,"%s", dm);
```

The * symbol declares an indirection, namely, the variable pointed to by dm.  The fscanf line will declare dm as a reference to the string captured with the %s delimiter.  It will point to the address of the first char in the string.

What kit said is correct too, the strcmp command should be used, not the == compare, as == will just compare the addresses of the strings.

Edit:  What kit says below is correct.  All pointers should be allocated memory before they are used, or else should be cast to a pre-allocated memory space.  You can allocate memory like this:

```
dm = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * STRING_LENGTH);
```

where STRING_LENGTH is a maximum length of a possible string.  This memory allocation only has to be done once.

Comment: The code that you've provided here is *VERY DANGEROUS* and should not be used.

Char *dm is an uninitialized pointer, which means that it could be pointing to anything in memory.  fscanf will not allocate memory for the string input, it will attempt to copy the data into the space pointed to by dm.  In the best case scenario, dm will point to an innocent and empty area of memory, or just to 0x00000000 (which is the null pointer on most systems) and cause a null pointer exception.

In the worst case scenario it could cause fscanf to overwrite code or other variables with the string data!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you've declared 'dm' as a `char`, not a malloc'd `char*` or `char[BUFSIZE]`

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fscanf/

You'll also probably report incorrect line numbers, you'll need to scan the read-in buffer for '\n' occurences, and handle the case where your desired string lies across buffer boundaries.